# Inserting decimal numbers from DataGridView into MySQL using INSERT

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

everybody,

I want to insert data from a DateGridView table into MySQL. It works so far but as soon as there are decimal numbers then they are not stored as decimal in MySQL but as integers. The decimal places are not transferred. I tried to convert the data but without success. They are not stored as decimal numbers.
Thanks for the tips !!!!

Here is the code

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++) // dòng
        {
            string str = "server=test; database=test; uid=test; pwd=test;";
            MySqlConnection constr = new MySqlConnection(str);
            constr.Open();
            String cmdText = "INSERT INTO KPI_Kosten (Betrag, Tower, Jahr, Periode, Land) VALUES ('"
                                       + Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value) + "','"
                                       + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "','"
                                       + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value + "','"
                                       + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + "','"
                                       + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value + "' )";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, constr);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            constr.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Using SQL parameters will protect you from injection and most probably will also solve your issue

Comment: if youre data in your databsase is stored as an int, and youre trying to pass in a decimal... think square peg, round hole... its not going to work.  You need to change your data type in your SQL Table

Comment: Ensure data type of `Betrag` column is `decimal`. If you're using `int` or `bigint`, the decimal part will be truncated. Also use parameters instead of concatenating query string values for easier reading and security.

Answer (score 0):

Since decimal places are truncated because column data type definition set to integer, first you should modify `Betrag` column to `decimal` data type with certain precision and scale like example below:

```
ALTER TABLE KPI_Kosten MODIFY COLUMN Betrag decimal(10, 2);
```

Afterwards, try setting `MySqlParameter` with parameterized query to enforce `decimal` data type with specified settings (see [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html)):

```
string str = "server=test; database=test; uid=test; pwd=test;";

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
     using (MySqlConnection constr = new MySqlConnection(str))
     {
         constr.Open();

         // if '@' prefix for parameters not working, change to '?'
         String cmdText = "INSERT INTO KPI_Kosten (Betrag, Tower, Jahr, Periode, Land) VALUES (@Betrag, @Tower, @Jahr, @Periode, @Land)";

         using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, constr))
         {
            // if you're experiencing too many parameters error, uncomment this line below
            // cmd.Parameters.Clear();

            MySqlParameter betrag = new MySqlParameter("@Betrag", MySqlDbType.Decimal);

            betrag.Precision = 10;
            betrag.Scale = 2;
            betrag.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);

            cmd.Parameters.Add(betrag);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Tower", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;

            // other parameters

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
     }
}
```

**Note:** You can also try simplified version without precision like `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Betrag", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);`.